# incremented included php pages one by one

Tags: php, include, increment

As you see I use this code to increment photos in a file, one by one :

```
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i <= $photonumber; $i++) {
    if($i < 10){

        echo '<div class="photos"><a target="_blank"><img src="../photosfile/' . $nom . '0' . $i . '.jpg"/></a></div>';     
        }
    else
        {
        echo '<div class="photos"><a target="_blank"><img src="../photosfile/' . $nom . $i . '.jpg"/></a></div>';  
        }
}
?>
```

I would like to do the same but with php pages reading them from a specific directory like : `../phppages/`

Any idea?

I tried but I missed something I guess and I would like to do it same way but with .php instead of .jpg.

Thank you very much.

Comment: "in a specific file like : ../phppages/" - specific file or specific dir?

Comment: @user4035 dir ! sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
for ($i = $photonumber; $i >= 1; $i--) {
    if($i < 10){
        $i = "0".$i;
    }

    include("../phppages/page".$i.".php");
}
?>
```

### Update: output by 3

```
<?php
$photonumber = 12;
for ($i = 0; $i < $photonumber; $i++) {

    $j = $photonumber - $i;
    if($j < 10){
        $j = "0".$j;
    }

    if ($i % 3 === 0)
    {
        if ($i !== 0)
        {
            echo '</div>';
        }
        echo '<div>';
    }

    include("../phppages/page". $j.".php");
}

echo '</div>';
```

### Update 2

To find the amount of files, that look like "page".$j.".php" in "../phppages" directory try this:

```
$files = glob("../phppages/page*.php");
$photonumber = count($files);
```

Comment: thank you @user4035. there is no problem if pages are like this 01, 02, 03...10 ?

Comment: an other question, what if i want to reverse the order ? the last one appear at first ? Thank you very much

Comment: @benjamingost I updated the answer. You need to start from the end and go backwards.

Comment: ok thank you, i need to study your code to understand and test it. Last question, what if i don't want to include 1 by one, but 3 by 3 ? i mean at the end it says 'include the last 3'.

Comment: @benjamingost Sorry, I don't understand, what you mean. Update your question and tell us what numbers do you want to include, and what - to exclude.

Comment: i posted my question not as a comment to make you see what i mean. in the same page.

Comment: @benjamingost I updated the answer. It will output 3 items in a block of divs in reverse order.

Comment: @user035 thank you very much for you help, i will study it and learn a lot for sure.

Comment: @benjamingost If $photonumber is not a multiple of 3, it will work correctly. The last element will be {02,01} or {01}.

Comment: Thank you @user4035, it works well ! is there a way to define (detect) $photonumber by counting all the "news ... .php" in the dir ? instead of writing it.

Comment: i havn't seen your comment, i just deleted my last question about multiple of 3, because it works well as you say.

Comment: @benjamingost You can use glob function. I'll try to provide a sample code for you later - a little bit busy now.

Comment: ok thank you, this is nice. i will investigate about glob function, then i will understand better.

Comment: hello @user4035 do you have any idea about this point ? ty very

Comment: @benjamingost I updated the answer. Let me know, whether it worked.

Answer (score 0):

That would just be this:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $photonumber; $i++) {
    include ('php-file-' . $i . '.php');
}
```

Comment: Hi Votey, thank you, but as you see i have a system which detect the "0" exemple page01.php, page02.php ... then you mean i have to forget it ? it works like this ?

Answer (score 0):

About having it 3 by 3, to be more precise, i want to create a  fore each 3 .php file. Like

```
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i <= $photonumber; $i++) {
if($i < 10){
echo '<div>';
include("../phppages/page".$i.".php") x3;
echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Then it become something like this :

> div : 12.php + 11.php + 10.php , div : 09.php + 08.php + 07.php , div 
>   :
>   06.php + 05.php + 04.php , div : 03.php + 02.php + 01.php